# Is it OK to ask questions about Minecraft server tools like Thermos, seeking help with some issues regarding them which do not involve crashes?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

The title pretty much has it. I am trying to use Minecraft Thermos (a thing to use Forge mods and plugins for Minecraft 1.7.10) and I have some minor (?) issues regarding this software. It is no longer officially supported, so the developer won't help me, so I wanted to ask some questions here, but I wonder if it is OK, as Minecraft crash questions regarding the non-vanilla game are off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are they gameplay questions?  As in how it works in-game, it's mechanics, and the specific things it brings to the table?  Those, you can ask about.

If you're asking for help getting the software working, that's not going to be something we can help with.  We *may* be able to help if the software is already working, and just needs some tweaking, but that's going to be more iffy.